# How to use printf for strings?

Tags: c++

So this is my code

```
string name;
cout <<"\n   Enter Your name : \n";
cin >> name;
printf("%s" , name);
```

and for some weird reasons codeblocks crashes at this

why ?

also how could I fix it ?

thanks

Comment: Don't mix `std::cout` with `printf`. Both are buffered, but uses *different* buffers, which may make your output unexpected.

Comment: Mixing C++-style and C-style I/O is perfectly well-defined as long as you have't called `ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`. It may be bad style, though.

Answer (score 3):

You should compile with all warnings (e.g. `g++ -Wall`). You'll get a useful warning. You want to use [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) like this

```
printf("%s", name.c_str());
```

BTW, why use `printf`and why do you forget a `\n` at the end of the `printf` format string? (or use `fflush`)

Better code:

```
cout << name << endl;
```

Comment: thank you ! I was testing printf , this was just a small part of the code
I want to make a text based rpg & I feel printf would take less space without all those "<<" used in cout

Answer (score 2):

If you *need* to pass your `std::string` to a function that accepts / uses C-style strings (`const char *`) for input, use `.c_str()`. It returns a `const char *`.

This is what you should do when needing to work with existing libraries, system calls, etc. For your own code, it is usually better to find a more C++ way of doing it.

In this case:

```
std::cout << name << std::endl;
```